# error 500 in weblogic8.1

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have started working on servlets. I am using weblogic server 8.1.
While running my servlet, i am getting an error 500(internal server error).
I asked about the problem, many of them said that the path is not set. but i have checked it 10 times and i am unable to detect the problem.

Pth variable includes `"C:\bea\jdk141_02\bin;"`
Do i need to remove the path for `jdk6?because weblogic8.1 requires jdk1.4` to run the program?
I am stucked on my very first program :D
Please help.. thnks in advance

Comment: The HTTP 500 error is usually result of an exception and usually shows the entire exception and stacktrace in the error page. The exception and the stacktrace is at its own usually already the whole answer to your problem. If you can't interpret what the exception is trying to tell you, you should not ignore it, but copypaste it in your question so that we can translate it in layman's terms for you.  Once you understood it, the solution should be obvious enough.

Comment: Error 500--Internal Server Error

javax.servlet.ServletException: [HTTP:101249][ServletContext(id=19000951,name=s1,context-path=/s1)]: Servlet class Demo for servlet Demo could not be loaded because the requested class was not found in the classpath C:\bea\user_projects\mydomain\myserver\upload\s1.war;C:\bea\user_projects\mydomain\.\myserver\.wlnotdelete\extract\myserver_s1_s1\jarfiles\_wl_cls_gen.jar.
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Demo (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0).

Comment: i guess there is a problem in setting the path. here it is..  

classpath="C:\bea\weblogic81\server\lib\weblogic.jar;."  

path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\lib;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\Sudhir\Documents\My DAP Downloads\eclipse;C:\bea\jdk141_02\bin;%PROGRAMFILES%\Internet Explorer;" 

if any one can help and find out the problem... :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments you got the following exception:

> ```
> Servlet class Demo for servlet Demo could not be loaded because the requested class was not found in the classpath 
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Demo (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)
> ```

The `Demo` servlet was been compiled using Java 1.6, while your Weblogic server apparently uses an older Java version. You need to recompile the `Demo` servlet using a Java version which is supported by your Weblogic server.

Another option is to get rid of that `Demo` servlet altogether and just create servlets yourself based on self-respected tutorials.